# How to check if a class is declared in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a piece of software around a framework and a class I am using (to be precise, extending) was renamed in a later version. Is there some way to write some macros/templates in C++11 in order to determine if a class with a certain name had been declared at the point in code?

An illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish follows.
Let's say that file class_include.h contains either the definition of class `A`:

```
class A
{ 
...
};
```

or class `B`:

```
class B
{ 
...
};
```

and class `C` tries to extend whichever of those is declared:

```
#include <class_include.h>

#if (class A is declared)
class C : public A
#else // class B is declared
class C : public B
#endif
{
...
};
```

Note: It came to my mind to try and check a version of the framework but the answer to this question interests me. I also **cannot** change any framework header files.

EDIT: The accepted answer depends on whether the class is defined (which implies declaration) and, in my case, the class is declared iff it's defined.

Comment: And when both A and B are declared (not saying it'll impact the answer; but you should certainly know what you want to happen)

Comment: They will not be declared at the same time. As I said, A was at one point renamed into B. That being said, a compile error would be preferable in this hypothetical situation.

Comment: As an aside, this was a really poor decision on the part of the library maintainer, unless they ran both side by side for a few versions and you ignored a deprecation warning? ;)

Comment: No warnings, just code working with an older version and me trying to upgrade to the new version. Then, this issue popped up. Admittedly, I still lack detailed knowledge of the library.

Comment: Why don't include corresponding class header according to the version number?

Comment: @serge All versions declare the classes in the same header file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can, and with no macros required. First an observation, you can "forward" declare a class even after its full definition is available. I.e. this is valid:

```
class foo{};
class foo;
```

Now, with the help of a homebrew `void_t` implementation and an `is_complete` type utility, you can do something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template <typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete<T, ::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T) != 0)>> : std::true_type {};

class A;
class B;

class C : public std::conditional<is_complete<A>::value, A, B>::type {
};
```

Depending on whether or not the full definition of `A` is present, `C` will inherit from `A` or `B` publicly. [See a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3858bc87009e7cf9).

But I caution, this needs to be handled with care or you are very likely to have an ODR-violation in your program.

Comment: Note that `is_complete` is dangerous as it may produce ODR violation (Ill-formed program NDR :-( ) easily as it should be consistent across TUs.

Comment: Now look at this, you beat me by a whole *minute* with the same idea. I must be rusty ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 - Nothing ventured nothing gained. Maybe in C++20 we can do this with less danger? Fingers crossed anyway.

Comment: How does this work if both `A` and `B` are abstract?

Comment: @nm_tp - Should work just the same. `sizeof` isn't barred from being applied to abstract classes, and it simply cannot evaluate to `0` for any object type. The "abstract" only means logical abstraction.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the template magic ideas already given, the traditional approach is to use the library's "version" macros if possible. If there aren't any, can't you just change your code and start using the new version of the library? Denote the new version of the dependency in your build system as appropriate.

Ultimately, dependency control is a normal and expected part of the software deployment process. So, even though it can be a bit of a pain in the arse, I wouldn't overcomplicate your code solely in attempt to completely eliminate it. I mean you already have to list the library in some form as a dependency so you're halfway there before you've even started!

The other answers do technically achieve your goal, as long as we assume that "class A is defined" can be considered equivalent to "class A is defined and takes the form of exactly what we think it should take the form of". Without working dependency control you are already kind of screwed, and with it you do not need hacks.

Comment: This is definitely something I would do, too, but the client might not want to be able to use various versions. I shall definitely try to use the version macros. +1

Comment: @nm_tp Ultimately, dependency control is a normal and expected part of the software deployment process. So, even though it can be a bit of a pain in the arse, I wouldn't overcomplicate your code solely in attempt to completely eliminate it. I mean you already have to list the library in _some_ form as a dependency so you're halfway there before you've even started!

Comment: This is actually the only right answer here. The other answers check if the *class is defined* not if the class *is declared* as written in the question!

Comment: @Oliv: While the wording in the question is imprecise, the intent/goal is clear. The other answers do technically achieve that goal, as long as we assume that "class A is defined" can be considered equivalent to "class A is defined and takes the form of exactly what we think it should take the form of". Without working dependency control you are already kind of screwed, and with it you do not need hacks.

Comment: In fact I'm going to add some of this commenty stuff into the answer

Comment: Well, I was precise, AFAIK. I need to check which of those is declared. Its definition lies inside a statically linked library and the only one that is defined inside the library is the one that's declared.

Comment: I don't know what you consider a hack. I can't image there are no observable like a macro or the existence of an include file that could be checked in its header file, the same way it is checked in the framework file.

Comment: @nm_tp But you need it to be defined (in the header!) to inherit from it. Ultimately whether its name is declared doesn't really matter, a fact that the template answers rely on.

Comment: Also, as much as I completely agree that dependency control is the way to go, I am quite interested in how to solve this in code. :)

Comment: @Oliv: I consider every overblown template metagubbins given here to be a hack. One author even claims it "simplifies things quite a bit"!! Checking for a header guard is a hack but a better one. Checking for a version macro is perfect but _probably_ unnecessary (though I have done this before with Boost when the sink API changed and caused me different behaviour at runtime; ugh)

Comment: Sorry to have worried you, I understood your first comment directed to me as meaning the opposite of what you actualy wrote!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit by template metaprogramming standards, it *is* quite simple ;)

Answer (score 6):

One way is to exploit SFINAE using `typeid` which will have a different result from an incomplete type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo> // for typeid

template<typename T, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_defined = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_defined<T, decltype(typeid(T), void())> = true;

struct complete {}; // i.e. `complete` is defined.
struct incomplete; // not defined, just a forward declaration

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_defined<complete> << " " << is_defined<incomplete>;
}
```

This requires you to forward declare the classes though, but as `is_defined` is `constexpr` it can be used at compile time. You could use `sizeof` too but I'm nervous about empty base class optimisations yielding false positives.

Comment: Note that `is_defined` is dangerous as it may produce ODR violation (Ill-formed program NDR :-( ) easily as it should be consistent across TUs.

Comment: Fear not, `sizeof` anything will always be at least 1. Taking EBO into account in such a context would be maddeningly complex anyway.

Comment: The question is "when the class is *declared*".

Comment: This causes several compiler errors. Which compiler and compile flags are you using? I tried with `g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

In your case, since you want to inherit from the class, it has to be declared but also defined; and this simplifies things quite a bit.

```
namespace detail_detectDefinedClass {
    template <class Void, class First, class... Rest>
    struct detect : detect<Void, Rest...> { };

    template <class First, class... Rest>
    struct detect<std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(First))>, First, Rest...> {
        using type = First;
    };
}

template <class... Classes>
using DetectDefinedClass = typename detail_detectDefinedClass::detect<
    std::void_t<>, Classes...
>::type;

struct A /* B */ {

};

class C : public DetectDefinedClass<struct A, struct B> {

};

static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<A, C>);
//static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B, C>);
```

This uses SFINAE by trying to use `sizeof` on the requested type, which only works if the type has been defined (`struct A` in the template's argument list merely declares it).

Comment: Note that `DetectDefinedClass` is dangerous as it may produce ODR violation (Ill-formed program NDR :-( ) easily as it should be consistent across TUs.

Comment: So the question when it is declared, and your code cause the declaration of the two classes.

Comment: @Oliv As I wrote in my answer, this checks whether the classes are defined, not merely declared.

Comment: @YSC no reason, it remained from a previous iteration but is indeed useless now.

Comment: As stated in the link that follows, the void_t has been available since C++17. Or am I missing something? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

Comment: @nm_tp I missed that you were in C++11 (don't forget language version tags!). `void_t` is easily implementable in C++11, see [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298134/3233393).

Comment: Sorry, new to the active community. Been only lurking until recently. StoryTeller's answer seems very nice so far but I need to test it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a type alias and select the right one according to the library version

```
#ifdef LIB_VER_123 
typedef A A1;
#else
typedef B A1;
#endif

class C : public A1
{ 
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think that it's clear from my question that I can't do that. This would be a perfect solution but I can't obtain the version.

Comment: You may introduce the version yourself when compiling with a different versions. I.e. as a compiler/preprocessor option `-D LIB_VER_123`

Comment: Yes! How could I've forgot this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the class code guard:

```
//classA.h
#ifndef cgA
#define cgA
class A {};
#endif

//classB.h
#ifndef cgB
#define cgB
class B {};
#endif

//classC.h
#include classA.h
#include classB.h

#ifdef cgA
class C : public A
#else
class C : public B
#endif
```

Edit with extra comment info: You could add an empty classA.h and classB.h and refer to them as last in your includepath. If you framework does not contain A or B the empty files will be loaded.

Comment: Quoting myself: "I also cannot change any framework include files."

Comment: What does that mean? You cannot change classA.h or classB.h? You could add an empty classA.h and classB.h and refer to them as last in your includepath. If you framework does not contain A or B the empty files will be loaded.

Comment: That doesn't really follow Frederik unless I'm misunderstanding you. However the idea to check whether the header guard of the desired header is defined is actually a good one, as long as it changed along with the name of the class within it.

Comment: This is the first thing that came to my mind but is just not feasible in my situation, as I have stated.

Comment: @nm_tp Why not? It doesn't require changing any framework include files. Unless the headers are weird, the guards are there, already, ready-made and ready to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are guards but they carry the same name: the name of the file (which remained the same).

Answer (score 0):

If the type/class you want to check is defined in a single header, in C++-17, you can use`__has_include`. Example:

```
#ifdef __has_include( <header_that_defines_the_class.hpp> )
// here the class is defined
#else
// there the class is not defined
#endif
```