# Conditionally define a member variable depending on the existence of the type it is made of

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a struct for data:

```
struct TestData {
}
```

and a class with a member variable:

```
class TestContainer {
private:
  TestData data;
};
```

Both are defined in a cpp file from a macro that is used in multiple test files.

Now I want to remove the data member at compile time if there is no TestData struct defined. If a test doesn't need data then there's no need to define the data member (and it would produce a warning for not being used). I thought of using `std::enable_if` but failed to come up with a condition. Another approach would be to define a base template class and specializations as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492589/can-i-use-sfinae-to-selectively-define-a-member-variable-in-a-template-class), but how to specialize on the existence of a type?

How can this be done?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53297795/3233393)? Although just disabling the warning sounds way easier and cleaner to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the type `TestData` is sometime defined and sometime not?

Comment: Exactly, but I could also live with the idea of having an undefined vs. a defined type (by forward declaring TestData in the init section of the test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a struct exist or not if you consider a forward declaration is not existing.

This example assume that either `TestData` is always defined or never defined:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Comment this line to trigger the static assert
struct TestData {};

template<typename, typename = void>
struct MaybeData {};

template<typename T>
struct MaybeData<T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>> {
    T data;
};

struct TestContainer : MaybeData<struct TestData> {};
```

We can test our solution like this:

```
template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr auto has_data = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto has_data<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::data)>> = true;

static_assert(has_data<TestContainer>);
```

The mechanism behind this is instead of sending the struct itself (`TestData`) as a type, we are using `struct TestData` as an argument, which refers to the type if it exist, but forward declare it if not.

Then, we use sfinae to check if `sizeof(T)` is a valid expression. If `TestData` is an imcomplete type, the expression is not valid.

However, if the completeness of a type changes between instantiation of the template, the program is ill formed.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/nEeJuU)